# Difference between "admit" and "accept"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Which of the options sounds correct?

> She has been **accepted/admitted** at York University.

Comment: *Accepted* and *admitted* mean different things. What do you want your sentence to mean? What event does it refer to? Being assured of a place at Your University, or taking up that place and becoming a student there?

Comment: Oh my, I have mispelt the name of university, it should be 'York University'. Anyway, the second meaning is what I need.

Comment: Taking up the place is ***admitted***.

Comment: See also [academia.se]

Comment: What country / region are you from?  I think that will make a big difference here.

Comment: @andi I think it doesn't really matter beacause I'm not a native speaker. However, it would be interesting to know if there are some differneces in the meaning between the regions/countries.

Comment: OK, well, I am from NYC.  @AndrewLeach said "taking up the place is _admitted_" but I would not say the same thing.  Being accepted to XY is when a student receives a letter saying "Congratulations, we hope you'll pick our school".  Admitted means the same as accepted, but isn't as commonly used here.  "She enrolled at XY" could mean paying your deposit and reserving your spot, and matriculated is a formal way of saying actually started taking classes as a full-time student.  But in casual conversation, people wouldn't say matriculated; they'd just say "she started school at XY".

Comment: Given that the question has been corrected to *York University* it seems clear to me that this is UK. A [british-english] tag (or whatever, if I'm wrong) would help, though.

Answer (score 1):

They can both mean the same thing but "admitted" is [usually](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admitted+*+university&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cadmitted%20%2A%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Badmitted%20to%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badmitted%20into%20university%3B%2Cc0) paired with "to":

> She has been admitted to York University.

"Accepted" [can work](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accepted+*+university&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Caccepted%20%2A%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Baccepted%20the%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20for%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20a%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20by%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20at%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20into%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20as%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20in%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20that%20university%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Baccepted%20to%20university%3B%2Cc0) with many different prepositions but in this context the most appropriate would be:

> She has been accepted into York University.
>
> She has been accepted to York University.
>
> She has been accepted at York University.

The relevant word definitions, by the way:

> [admit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/admit) — to allow to enter; grant or afford entrance to: "to admit a student to college."
>
> [accept](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accept) — To admit to a group, organization, or place: "accepted me as a new member of the club."

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is a matter of nuance. In the US, being accepted by a university is pretty much the same as being admitted to one.

But, if someone told me they were accepted, I might ask when they'll be going. And they might respond that they were admitted for the Fall Quarter.

Here, I see accept as: to receive with approval or favor. Admit is to permit, give access to or egress to.

Comment: When you admit, it's all about your action and views. When you accept, it's generally others'.